# Does using a custom authorizer with aws-iot (wss) create a new device everytime a device connects and sends data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot, lambda-authorizer

Considering there are a bunch of mobile devices (Android and iOS) that need to be sending data to AWS-IoT via MQTT [custom authorizer to check for valid token based on business logic](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/configuring-cognito-user-pools-to-communicate-with-aws-iot-core/) is to be implemented.

Referring to [IoT Apps with AWS IoT and Websockets](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/iot-apps-with-aws-iot-and-websockets), slide 56/60 shows the registration process where a lambda is used to create and attach a policy.

Does this indicate that the lambda will create a new AWS-IoT device and attach the policy to that device? Which results in creating a new AWS-IoT device everytime a new user signs up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [How to Use Your Own Identity and Access Management Systems to Control Access to AWS IoT Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-your-own-identity-and-access-management-systems-to-control-access-to-aws-iot-resources)
, you can create your custom-authorizer. Once that's done, you can use [aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js) to test out the authorizer by using [this piece of code](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#device-class).

- Using custom authorizer doesn't require you to create or have any
  things registered in your account.
- You are billed for your connections, messages etc as per AWS's IoT pricing.

However this is a mqtt over wss implementation and not a mqtt only implementation. As of now, the mqtt only implementation still seems to require certificates during connection to the AWS-IoT broker.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on user2967920's answer:

1. You do not need to create devices when using AWS IoT Core. AWS Amplify PubSub actually uses IoT as a general-purpose MQTT broker. No devices will be created by using a custom authorizer*.
2. The policy returned by your custom authorizer is not persisted. Think of it as a dynamic, ad-hoc policy created for a specific connection.

For an example of using AWS IoT on Android and iOS, check out the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/pubsub/working-api/q/platform/ios/#custom-authentication) of AWS Amplify PubSub (which uses AWS IoT Core internally). On iOS:

```swift
iotDataManager.connectUsingWebSocket(withClientId: uuid,
                                     cleanSession: true,
                                     customAuthorizerName: "<name-of-the-custom-authorizer>",
                                     tokenKeyName: "<key-name-for-the-token>",
                                     tokenValue: "<token>",
                                     tokenSignature: "<signature-of-the-token>",
                                     statusCallback: mqttEventCallback)
```

*Obviously you can create devices in the lambda function if you choose to, just like you can use any other AWS API.

Comment: what's the token value? How do i get this ?

Comment: @karticchaudhary depends on your application, check out the AWS docs. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-your-own-identity-and-access-management-systems-to-control-access-to-aws-iot-resources/